# Refresh only update panel on parent from pop-up window

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, popup, updatepanel

I have a button which opens a pop-up window and an Ajax update panel. Inside that window I have another button.

What code do I have to run if I want that update panel to be refreshed, when I press the button from the parent page, without refreshing the whole page?

I sow this code on a web which refreshes the page:

```
<div id="Container" onclick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');">
```

I am such a good friend with Java.

Comment: "I am such a good friend with Java." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to utilize [window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp#gsc.tab=0) object.

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('Container').onclick();
```

I'd suggest using jQuery to ensure cross-browser compatibility. And also adding some null-checks of course.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am such a good friend with Java so I ask you to help my again. I added a button on my opener window, btnSave, and one in the opened page, 'save'. When I press the 'save' button, I added the following code to run:  <!-- language: lang-js --> Response.Write(@"<script>window.opener.document.getElemtnById('btnSave').onclick();</script>"); And now the page is reopening in a new browser's tab.

Comment: And what is in the btnSave's onclick? It seems that there is a code for opening the window. You need to call onclick of element that refreshes the updatepanel.

Comment: The btnSave refreshes the page. I receive the following error from FireBug when I press the button: TypeError: window.opener.document.getElemtnById is not a function

Comment: I'm sorry there was a typo in the code. It is getElementById.

Comment: Yes and instead of onclick is just click. And I had to change the button ID with the Asp.Net generated one. But works! Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery :

If the DIV ID remains static :

```
$("#Container").click(function() {
  // REFRESH CONTAINER HERE
});
```

If the Div ID is dynamic then make use of class instead of ID:

```
$(".Container").click(function() {
  // REFRESH CONTAINER HERE
});
```